# CSS Select first sibling paragraph that contains a link

Tags: css, css-selectors

A coworker asked me whether if a knew how to do the following selection and frankly I'm not even sure if it can be done using just CSS.

Let's say that having the following structure:

```
<div>
  <h4>Foo</h4>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Bar</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to select all **a** that are contained in the first **p** that is a sibling of an h4 that contains **foo**.

I've already tried with `h4 + p > a` but it will only select it if there is no other p before (it get false negative on the first **div**):

```css
h4 + p > a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Foo</h4>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Bar</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I've already tried with `h4 ~ p > a` but it will select all **p** and not only the first one (it get false positive on the **bar** paragraphs):

```css
h4 ~ p > a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Foo</h4>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Bar</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

What am I missing? Can it even be done?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with css, add a class the anchors and you are set, why try to come up with some complicated selector

Comment: Alternative approach https://jsfiddle.net/ofrksn7p/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. T problem is that the target HTML is NOT generated by us, so we cannot modify it (we're using a CSS selector bases page crawler). I'll delete the answer as it clearly won't go anywhere and is not worth keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with pure CSS.

You cannot add content of an element into your CSS selector.

To do this on the fly you would need to either amend your HTML markup or apply some javascript.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. The problem is that the target HTML is NOT generated by us, so we cannot modify it (we're using a CSS selector bases page crawler). I'll delete the answer as it clearly won't go anywhere and is not worth keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently use element content as a CSS selector. If you can add classes either statically or dynamically in whatever is generating your HTML, you would be able to use CSS selectors to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. T problem is that the target HTML is NOT generated by us, so we cannot modify it (we're using a CSS selector bases page crawler). I'll delete the answer as it clearly won't go anywhere and is not worth keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

Style definition should be like this and In h4+p, here p does not need any selector if you want to select only the first one

```css
div > h4+p > a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Foo</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>bar</p> 
  
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Bar</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. T problem is that the target HTML is NOT generated by us, so we cannot modify it (we're using a CSS selector bases page crawler). I'll delete the answer as it clearly won't go anywhere and is not worth keeping it.